# PHP/MYSQL: Count number of characters before '.' or specific character

Tags: php, mysql, count, character

I am trying to count how many characters a domain have before its extension. How do I count the number of characters before the '.'?

As I have a few records in my MySQL database:

```
example.com
test.net
domain.co
```

The output will be

```
7
4
6
```

How do I do it using PHP or MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the substring that is on the right of the first '.'. Applying `LENGTH` on the substring returns the required result:

```
SELECT LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain, '.', 1))
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bfde/2)

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it works even when there is no '.' in `domain`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple query would be this:

```
SELECT (LOCATE('.', `column`) - 1) AS `length`
FROM `table`
```

`LOCATE()` will return the exact position of the character, so subtracting 1 will give you the length of the characters before that.